# Button keeps submitting other events (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 buttons in my form. One button is for preview only and the other one is for submitting form through AJAX

```
 <form id="form" action="" class="form" method="POST">
    <button id="btn_preview" type="button">  Preview </button>
    <button id="btn_save" type="submit">  Save </button>                                                                                
 </form>
```

My problem is when I click the ***button id="btn_preview"*** it always fires the event in ***button id="btn_save"***. How will I fix this?

```
$('#btn_preview').click(function () {

    form = $('form');

    form.attr({
              'target':'_blank',
              'action':'https://www.google.com'
             }).submit();

    return false;

});

$("#btn_save").closest('form').on('submit', function() {

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'URL',
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       success: function(data) {

          alert("Success!");                          

       }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: You have syntax error please check you console for this

Comment: You have syntax error: please check here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39342545/1960558

Comment: sorry its typo error when i typed here in stack.. but still does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error "})"

```
$('#btn_preview').click(function () {

        alert("Preview");
        return false;

    });

    $("#btn_save").closest('form').on('submit', function() {

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'URL',
           data: $('form').serialize(),
           success: function(data) {

              alert("Success!");                          

           }
        });

        return false;

    });
```

Comment: sorry its typo error when i typed here in stack.. but still does not work..

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your jquery code. Please update it with below one. The click event should finish with `});` not `)};`

```
$('#btn_preview').click(function (event) {    
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Preview");
});

$("#btn_save").closest('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: 'URL',
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       success: function(data) {

          alert("Success!");                          

       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry its typo error when i typed here in stack.. but still does not work..

Comment: Use event.preventDefault(); to stop form submition. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Ruhul Patel, Hi, See my updated and actual code, I think the problem is the .submit(); in btn_preview event, that's why it fires the event in btn_save?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error in your code, Please update it with below one. The click event and on submit should finish with `});` not `)};`

```
$('#btn_preview').click(function(){
 alert("Preview");
 return false;
});

$("#btn_save").closest('form').on('submit', function() {

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'URL',
   data: $('form').serialize(),
   success: function(data) {

      alert("Success!");                          

   }
  });

   return false;

 });
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s3s1hbxz/4/

You can also modify your code to target only form by `id` or `class`. For you case you html code `<form id="form" action="" class="form" method="POST">
    <button id="btn_preview" type="button">  Preview </button>
    <button id="btn_save"  type="submit">  Save </button>

    </form>`

So you can try like this:

```
$('#btn_preview').click(function(){
 alert("Preview");
 return false;
 });

$("form#form").on('submit', function() {

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'URL',
   data: $('form').serialize(),
   success: function(data) {

      alert("Success!");                          

   }
  });

  return false;

});
```

It's means, it will trigger only `submit` button hit. jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s3s1hbxz/5/

Comment: sorry its typo error when i typed here in stack.. but still does not work..

Comment: Hi, See my updated and actual code, I think the problem is the .submit(); in btn_preview event, that's why it fires the event in btn_save?? Thanks

Comment: @DafnyCruz I am asking again, did you check my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/s3s1hbxz/4/? did you run it? did you find any error? if yes then let me know which error please. There are other way to solve this problem

Comment: hi sir, i've already saw it and tested it. My problem now is i have _.submit();_ in _btn_preview events_, you can check my updated code above. thanks

Comment: @DafnyCruz, you called .submit() . so submit button triggered at the end. What exactly you wanna do with preview button?

Comment: _$('form').attr({'target':'_blank', 'action':'https://www.google.com' }).submit();_ i want to execute this code..